# How to validate a specific jsonschema based on document type

Tags: python, schema, jsonschema

I have a JSON schema for user's new message:

```
message_creation = {
    "title": "Message",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "post": {
            "oneOf": [
                {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "content": {
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    },
                    "additionalProperties": False,
                    "required": ["content"]
                },
                {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "image": {
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    },
                    "additionalProperties": False,
                    "required": ["image"]
                },
                {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "video_path": {
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    },
                    "additionalProperties": False,
                    "required": ["video"]
                }
            ]
        },
        "doc_type": {
            "type": "string",
            "enum": ["text", "image", "video"]
        }
    },
    "required": ["post", "doc_type"],
    "additionalProperties": False
}
```

It's simple as that! There is two fields one is `type` and the other is `post`. So a payload like below succeeds:

```
{
    "post": {
        "image": "Hey there!"
    },
    "type": "image"
}
```

Now problem is that if user sets `type` value to `text` I cannot validate if text's schema has been given. How should I verify this? How should I check in case `type` is set to `image` then make sure that `image` exists  inside of post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it, but it's complicated. This uses a boolean logic concept called implication to ensure that if schema A matches then schema B must also match.

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "post": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "content": { "type": "string" },
        "image": { "type": "string" },
        "video_path": { "type": "string" }
      },
      "additionalProperties": false
    },
    "doc_type": {
      "type": "string",
      "enum": ["text", "image", "video"]
    }
  },
  "required": ["post", "doc_type"],
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "allOf": [
    { "$ref": "#/definitions/image-requires-post-image" },
    { "$ref": "#/definitions/text-requires-post-content" },
    { "$ref": "#/definitions/video-requires-post-video-path" }
  ],
  "definitions": {
    "image-requires-post-image": {
      "anyOf": [
        { "not": { "$ref": "#/definitions/type-image" } },
        { "$ref": "#/definitions/post-image-required" }
      ]
    },
    "type-image": {
      "properties": {
        "doc_type": { "const": "image" }
      }
    },
    "post-image-required": {
      "properties": {
        "post": { "required": ["image"] }
      }
    },
    "text-requires-post-content": {
      "anyOf": [
        { "not": { "$ref": "#/definitions/type-text" } },
        { "$ref": "#/definitions/post-content-required" }
      ]
    },
    "type-text": {
      "properties": {
        "doc_type": { "const": "text" }
      }
    },
    "post-content-required": {
      "properties": {
        "post": { "required": ["content"] }
      }
    },
    "video-requires-post-video-path": {
      "anyOf": [
        { "not": { "$ref": "#/definitions/type-video" } },
        { "$ref": "#/definitions/post-video-path-required" }
      ]
    },
    "type-video": {
      "properties": {
        "doc_type": { "const": "video" }
      }
    },
    "post-video-path-required": {
      "properties": {
        "post": { "required": ["video_path"] }
      }
    }
  }
}
```